# How to write browser related script using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I target different browsers using jQuery? For example the javascript for IE6 and IE7 needs to be different.

Comment: What is your question here?  Where have you started?  Are you looking for basic jQuery tutorials, or do you already have some code?  What is your code supposed to be doing?

Comment: He wants to target specific jQuery at specific browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for different browsers like this:

```
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version === 6)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could use conditional comments to include your scripts, like this perhaps:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/ie6.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This would be great if you wanted to target entire files at each browser, without having to send all the scripts down to each browser and then check.

Alternatively one of the other answers (at this time) tells you how to do it on a smaller scale.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest reading about feature detection. http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting wouldn't be a bad starting place.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery aims at cross-browser-compatibility, so usually there is no need to write different javascript for specific browsers. use the function provided my jQuery (or therefor any other javascript framework like mootools) and you shouldn't have any problems